# How to solve java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, mysql

This is the first time I got this error. 
This code basically gets the sum of each item sold in a particular date.

Any tips on resolving this problem? Thanks.

> ```
>        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
>        String query = "SELECT itemcode, SUM(quantity) AS 'Total Sales Per Day' "
>                + "FROM sales "
>                + "WHERE real_pur_date = '" + date + "' "
>                + "GROUP BY itemcode ";
>        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery( query ); // this line gets the error / exception
>        while( rs.next() ){
>            Vector row = new Vector();
>            row.add( rs.getString( "itemcode" ) );
>            row.add( rs.getInt( "Total Sales Per Day" ) );
>            dailyData.add( row );
>        }
>        statement.close();
> ```

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:431)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInstance(ResultSetImpl.java:383)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.buildResultSetWithRows(MysqlIO.java:3140)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:491)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:3118)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2288)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2709)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2677)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2627)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1556)
at posinventory.Controller.StatisticEngine.getDailyData(StatisticEngine.java:20)
at posinventory.Statistic.refreshTableDailyStat(Statistic.java:36)
at posinventory.Statistic.refreshTableDailyStat(Statistic.java:37)
at posinventory.Statistic.refreshTableDailyStat(Statistic.java:37)
at posinventory.Statistic.refreshTableDailyStat(Statistic.java:37)
```

Comment: First thing: don't use Vector. Ever! Use an ArrayList instead.

Comment: You didn't paste enough of stacktrace to see the cycle. SOE is almost always the consequence of infinite recursion. On the odd chance that this is not the case here, the solution would be very simple: pass the JVM a parameter that increases the stack size.

Comment: Also, what's the `date` value that causes the `StackOverflowError`?

Comment: @Traroth, use a `Vector` if you need a dynamically resizing array in a **multi-threaded** environment?

Comment: @Traroth: What is wrong with a vector? `The Vector class implements a growable array of objects. Like an array, it contains components that can be accessed using an integer index. However, the size of a Vector can grow or shrink as needed to accommodate adding and removing items after the Vector has been created.`

Comment: [What is a Stackoverflow error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stack-overflow-error/214758#214758)

Comment: You also didn't paste enough code to tell what's going on. The stacktrace mentions "posinventory..." and nothing in the code (except maybe the mysterious, undeclared "dailyData" variable) should reference anything like that.

Comment: Another advise: __never__ use statement, it will lead to SQL Injection attacks. Instead, use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)s.

Comment: Keep in mind, too, that since you have a SOE, there is absolutely no problem with the line that threw the error. It's just the final straw that broke the camel's back.

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman The date value is 20120620

Comment: @Alex Lockwood, VanDarg: Vector is a list. And the framework offers really better lists.

Comment: @VanDarg [differences between Vector and ArrayList](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-collection/difference-between-vector-and-arraylist-in-java/).

Comment: Please specify your table structure and the size of the table. This may be the mistakes in the SQL query.

Comment: @AlexLockwood Vector is synchronized, but that by itself doesn't make it thread-safe. That's the crux of the argument against Vector: it wastes time on locking while providing little to no benefit

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: I am aware of the differences, there is no way to determine the **# of threads** from this code snippet.

Comment: @Alex Lockwood: if you need a synchronzed list, there are still better solutions than Vector, for example using Collections.synchronizedList()

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know that. Thanks. But I still question whether you should have said "never use `Vector`"... can someone confirm this?

Comment: @VanDarg looks like you haven't read the "Is there an alternate available in java for Vector?" section of that link.

Comment: @AlexLockwood see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1386288/1065197

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I refuse to accept this as the corre--ah, crap... it's Jon Skeet. :P (thanks for the link)

Comment: @Alex Lockwood : Vector, like Hashtable, is a relic from the pre-Java 2 era and should be avoided.

Comment: @AlexLockwood don't worry. Also, instead of `HashTable` you should use [`java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp07233/index.html).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I answer questions here because I learn something new everyday :). Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really should post the code from `posinventory.Statistic.refreshTableDailyStat`, but I'll guess at it: in that method, line 36 calls `StatisticEngine.getDailyData`; line 37 calls `refreshTableDailyStat` recursively -- so there's your problem, `Statistic.java`, line 37.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think the code snippet you included is the problem. Looking at the bottom of your stack trace, I see Statistic.java:37 apparently calling itself several times. Recursive calls are allowed, but they lead to a stack overflow if they are not controlled. Looks like you have a loop...

Answer (score 2):

Remove the ::

String '+' from the query, as the JVM uses string pooling, for every type of string it calls a service to check whether that string is present or not.

Use String Builder instead.

Remove the Vector and Replace it with ArrayList, as Steve has mentioned above, check you code snippet where an unknown recursion has occurred .

Comment: In this case it makes no difference to use a StringBuilder instead.

Comment: String query = "SELECT itemcode, SUM(quantity) AS 'Total Sales Per Day' "
               + "FROM sales "
               + "WHERE real_pur_date = '" + date + "' "
               + "GROUP BY itemcode ";






can be replaced with a stringBuilder..

Comment: Wrong both of you. Even with a StringBuilder, that type of code leads to SQL Injection attacks. Instead, you should use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: @SashiKant Adding strings as in the question is fine, it will not be improved by a StringBuilder.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Of course a PreparedStatement should be used for the query, I was referring to the String concatenation vs StringBuilder.

Comment: @RogerLindsjö when you want to improve an answer, try to give the better guidance, don't try to make it a chance to long discussions or just checking the basic cases.